Self-join excluding joining a row to itself
Sometimes you want all pairs of rows in a table: its Cartesian product with itself.  That could be done with a join.
drop table if exists #a
create table #a (x int)
insert into #a values (1),(2),(3)
select *
from #a a1
join #a a2
  on 0 = 0 -- always-true join condition

That gives nine rows.
If I wanted to get pairs except where a row is paired with itself, I could add a join condition requiring different values of x:
select *
from #a a1
join #a a2
  on a1.x != a2.x

That gives only six rows in the result.  But I have assumed that column x is a unique identifier.  Suppose it isn't:
delete from #a
insert into #a values (4), (4), (5)

There are two rows in the table holding value 4.  They have identical values but nonetheless are separate rows and SQL does sometimes let you treat them separately (for example with set rowcount 1 update #a set x = 40 where x = 4 set rowcount 0).  I would still like to get all pairs of rows from a self-join but excluding pairs where a row is paired with itself.  So my desired output would be (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 4), (4, 5), (5, 4), (5, 4).  Still six rows in the output.
I have found one possible answer which I will post.  (Of course, there are answers like "add a second column" or "make sure the column x has unique values", or of course "don't try to make a Cartesian product", but I am interested to find out what facilities T-SQL offers.)

A related question ROWNUM as a pseudo column equivalent in T-SQL? suggests this solution
with t as (select *, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as rownum from #a)
select *
from t a1
join t a2
  on a1.rownum != a2.rownum

Checking the actual query plan (admittedly on this tiny toy table) shows that this doesn't introduce any extra sorting step, so should be reasonably fast, though perhaps not as fast as the native rownum provided by Oracle.

I think order by @@spid is the more simple order by if you don't care about sorting

Huh, yes, I guess @@spid works too but I'd see it as even more obfuscated than (select null).  It's all to put something which is constant, but not let the query planner see that it's constant as it will disallow it (why?).

In truth, it just need to be a constant, @siggemannen . SQL Server doesn't allow constants in the ORDER BY of an OVER clause, however, that can be avoided with things like a scalar subquery; it's not "clever" enough to work out that the scalar subquery results in a constant. You could use other configuation functions like @@VERSION, @@SERVERNAME, or @@LANGID. Like the author here, I tend to use (SELECT NULL), as it represents an unknown (order).

If you look at the execution plans for the row_number()-based queries, I see that there are two separate table-scan/segment/sequence paths. Makes me wonder if there is any guarantee that the assigned row numbers will be the same for both CTE references - especially when scaled up and parallel operations might sneak in. If you change the query to use over (order by newid()), you definitely get an unmatched ordering.

i think it was Aaron bertrand that wrote about @@spid, and i think @@TRANCOUNT could be used to remove parallelization from the ROW_NUMBER operator, but my memory is hazy :)

select *
from #a a1
join #a a2
  on a1.%%physloc%% != a2.%%physloc%%

This %%physloc%% is a loose equivalent of Oracle's rownum and gives the identity of the row on disk somehow.  But whereas it's fairly common to see rownum-based queries for Oracle, on MSSQL I've never come across %%physloc%% until now.
According to a comment on Can %%physloc%% be used as a row identifier or key for an on-the-fly query? the 'location' of a row might change even while a query is executing so this isn't a reliable technique.
